# If and how is this related to Grassmanians?

Tags: projective-geometry, grassmannian

Given a $n$ dimensional vector space over the finite field $F_q$, called $V(F_q)$, and a set of $M$ vectors $\vec c_m=(c_0,c_1,...c_{n-1})^T$ that fulfill $(\sum c_k )=0$. Further the complete set of $\{\vec c_m\}$ is symmetric under all permutations of elements of a given $\vec c_m$.

I'm searching $\vec s\in V(F_q)$, the  smallest (in the sense of the [taxicab norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)) element of $V(F_q)$ which has:

$$ \vec s \cdot \vec c_m  \neq 0 \bmod q, \forall m$$

If each $\vec c_m$ makes up an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, orthogonal to $\vec c_m$, my feeling says that $\vec s$ lies in the complement of union of all these subspaces.
If and how is this related to [Grassmanians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian)?
I ask because the [application of Gaussian Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Applications) tells us that

> the Gaussian binomial coefficient
> ${\displaystyle {n \choose k}_{q}}$
> counts the number of $k$-dimensional vector subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F_q$ (a Grassmannian).

Is the union of all these subspaces a Grassmanian?

Comment: "If each $\vec{c}_m$ makes up an $n−1$ dimensional subspace". What do you mean by this? The vector $\vec{c}_m$ belongs to an $n$-dimensional vector space, which you denote by $V(F_q)$. Which $n - 1$ dimensional subspace of $V(F_q)$ are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I clarified: If each $\vec c_m$ makes up an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, **orthogonal to $\vec c_m$**, my feeling says that $\vec s$ lies in the **complement of** union of all these subspaces.

Comment: I agree with that statement.

Comment: What makes you think that the problem you are trying to solve has anything to do with grassmannians?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I have a lot of permutational symmetry in my $c_m$ vectors, which resemble partitions in a certain sense, as does the vector $\vec s$ (Maybe I should mention that above) . So I started to search the web, which ended an Gaussian Binomial Coefficients, referring to Grassmanians. I want to know if it would help to understand and structure my problem when I dive into the Grassmanian Sea...

Comment: What do you mean by the taxicab norm in $V(F_q)$? The link describes a norm for real vector spaces.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I wanted to say that the length is calculated by $\sum_k |c_k| \bmod q$.

Comment: That could be zero though, even if $\vec{c}$ is non-zero.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese true. I never had that case (by construction of our search algorithm) so haven't thought about that option. As a first guess I would forget the mod q in that case. Maybe I should do that right away, but it looks like that it doesn't affect my previous numerical results

Comment: I don't think that there is any reasonable way to frame this problem in terms of grassmannians.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thanks for your opinion.